# How to prevent C# WinForm listview selection Change when key is pressed and list view auto find next row on the basis of first column

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

My listview is populated  from DB table
When I press a number key the list view auto  find that key in first column and change selection to that item. I haven't written any code for that purpose. I want to stop doing this.

Comment: What if you tried attaching a key event listener (keydown/previewkeydown?) to the listview, and then set `e.Handled` to true?

Comment: You will need to handle key presses yourself. There are many possibilities (my favorite is subclassing everything), the easiest is [SuppressKeyPress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.suppresskeypress).

Answer (score 0):

For finding item by first column when key pressed in ListView:

```
        private void listView1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)        
        {
            var i = 0;
            var data = listView1.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>()
                                 .Select((a,b)=>new { itemText = a.Text, index = i++ })
                                 .ToList();
            var findItem = data.Where(w => w.itemText.StartsWith(e.KeyValue.ToString())).FirstOrDefault();
            if (findItem == null)
                return;

            listView1.Items[findItem.index].Focused = true;
            listView1.Items[findItem.index].Selected = true;
            listView1.Items[findItem.index].EnsureVisible();
        }
```

Comment: Finding is occurring automatically. I wanted to stop this. I have resolved with suppress key press event on key down.